# Getting error when creating Picker Having Two components in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question has been asked before. but i having difficulty among those. as i have created picker by using this code.

```
  @interface datePicker ()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
    IBOutlet UITextField *tfTime;
    NSMutableArray *arrayData,*minData;
}


@end

@implementation datePicker

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrayData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    minData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayData addObject:@1];
    [arrayData addObject:@2];
    [arrayData addObject:@3];
    [arrayData addObject:@4];
    [arrayData addObject:@5];
    [arrayData addObject:@6];
    [arrayData addObject:@7];
    [arrayData addObject:@8];
    [arrayData addObject:@9];

    [minData addObject:@01];
    [minData addObject:@02];
    [minData addObject:@03];
    [minData addObject:@04];
    [minData addObject:@05];
    [minData addObject:@06];
    [minData addObject:@07];
    [minData addObject:@80];
    [minData addObject:@90];
    [minData addObject:@10];

    [picker setDataSource:self];
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    [self.view addSubview:picker];





    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


    if(component==0)
    {
        return [arrayData count];
    }

    else
    {
        return [minData count];
    }


}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   if(component==0)

    return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayData objectAtIndex:row]];

else

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[minData objectAtIndex:row]];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    tfTime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[arrayData objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]],[minData objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
}
```

@end
 But getting error like this

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}

and

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Show the whole error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding numbers to the array and you are retrieving as string. So replace your titleForRow method with following. It should work.

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:  (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if(component==0)
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayData objectAtIndex:row]];
else
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[minData objectAtIndex:row]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,because -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:  (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component, this method returns NSString object and your array contains integer object which is incompatible.